# fullcalendar.js showing dates twice from json input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscalendar

I am making a calendar based on dates coming from json input. The problem is even if my json data does not have duplicate dates. its showing two slots of same datetime in one day. I have tried to make the calendar a 24 hours supported calendar as well , but the issue is still there

```
http://jsfiddle.net/xpsg9pa4/28/
```

The js calendar code i am using.

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
      },
      defaultView:'agendaWeek',
      weekNumberCalculation:'ISO',
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      selectable: false,
      editable: false,
      validRange: {
        start: moment(new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).format('Y-MM-DD')
      },  
      weekNumbersWithinDays: true,
      navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events



events:[{"title":"17:30","start":"2018-09-27 17:30"},{"title":"18:30","start":"2018-09-27 18:30"},{"title":"19:30","start":"2018-09-27 19:30"},{"title":"20:30","start":"2018-09-27 20:30"},{"title":"21:30","start":"2018-09-27 21:30"},{"title":"22:30","start":"2018-09-27 22:30"},{"title":"23:30","start":"2018-09-27 23:30"},{"title":"00:30","start":"2018-09-28 00:30"},{"title":"01:30","start":"2018-09-28 01:30"},{"title":"02:30","start":"2018-09-28 02:30"},{"title":"15:30","start":"2018-09-28 15:30"},{"title":"17:30","start":"2018-09-28 17:30"},{"title":"18:30","start":"2018-09-28 18:30"},{"title":"19:30","start":"2018-09-28 19:30"},{"title":"20:30","start":"2018-09-28 20:30"},{"title":"21:30","start":"2018-09-28 21:30"},{"title":"22:30","start":"2018-09-28 22:30"},{"title":"23:30","start":"2018-09-28 23:30"},{"title":"00:30","start":"2018-09-29 00:30"},{"title":"01:30","start":"2018-09-29 01:30"},{"title":"02:30","start":"2018-09-29 02:30"},{"title":"15:30","start":"2018-09-29 15:30"},{"title":"17:30","start":"2018-09-29 17:30"},{"title":"18:30","start":"2018-09-29 18:30"},{"title":"19:30","start":"2018-09-29 19:30"},{"title":"20:30","start":"2018-09-29 20:30"},{"title":"21:30","start":"2018-09-29 21:30"},{"title":"22:30","start":"2018-09-29 22:30"},{"title":"23:30","start":"2018-09-29 23:30"},{"title":"00:30","start":"2018-09-30 00:30"},{"title":"01:30","start":"2018-09-30 01:30"},{"title":"02:30","start":"2018-09-30 02:30"},{"title":"17:30","start":"2018-09-30 17:30"},{"title":"18:30","start":"2018-09-30 18:30"},{"title":"19:30","start":"2018-09-30 19:30"},{"title":"20:30","start":"2018-09-30 20:30"},{"title":"21:30","start":"2018-09-30 21:30"},{"title":"22:30","start":"2018-09-30 22:30"},{"title":"23:30","start":"2018-09-30 23:30"},{"title":"00:30","start":"2018-10-01 00:30"},{"title":"01:30","start":"2018-10-01 01:30"},{"title":"02:30","start":"2018-10-01 02:30"}]
      });
```

The slots such as `2018-09-28 23:30` is being repeated two times

Answer (score 0):

The problem I assume is , if you dont give end time for an event , it is considering end time as +2 hours, 
If you give end time , it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As per the data available i dont have a end time. If i remove defaultView:'agendaWeek', which i need . it shows fine.

Comment: is there any way to fix this without having the end time as the source data is not under my control.